EF Core loses the primary keys for my objects during updates?
I am creating a fairly simple application with 3 tables that contain Members, Envelopes, and Mailing Addresses. There is a 1:1 relationship between a Member and each of the other tables (1 Envelope per Member and 1 Mailing Address per Member).
On the database, the Member table has a primary key (int), the Envelope table and the MailAddress table both have primary keys (int) and a foreign key into the Member table.
In the Member model in the code, the Member has the [Key] = MemberId and has 2 properties:
public virtual Envelope? Envelope { get; set; }
public virtual MailAddress? MailAddress { get; set; }

The Envelope model has the following:
[ForeignKey("MemberId")]
public int MemberId { get; set; }
public virtual Member? Member { get; set; }

The MailAddress model has the following:
[ForeignKey("MemberId")]
public int MemberId { get; set; }
public virtual Member? Member { get; set; }

When I select a Member to edit in a [HttpGet] method, I use the following code and it brings back everything just fine - I get the correct Member and it contains the correct Envelope and MailAddress objects. All of the fields in the 3 objects are available to edit on the view.
public Member Edit(int id)
{
    return _context.Member
                   .Where(m => m.MemberId == id)
                   .Include(e => e.Envelope)
                   .Include(a => a.MailAddress).FirstOrDefault();
}

However, after changes have been made in the view, when I call the [HttpPost] method to update the database, the Member that is returned from the view has the correctly changed fields, it has the correct Envelope and MailAddress objects, but all 3 of the primary key values have changed to zero.
How do I correct this so that the _context.SaveChanges() method will know what to update and stop throwing primary key missing exceptions?

are the primary keys part of your form data? @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberId) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Envelope.MemberId) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MailAddress.MemberId)

Could you please share your view codes and let us reproduce the issue?

@BryanDellinger - That was it - DOH!!  Thanks for the hint!
